# rubyからaws-sdkを使おうとするとエラーが起こる

Tags: ruby, aws, rubygems, amazon-s3

`gem install aws-sdk-core`の後に以下の読み込むだけのコードを実行するとエラーになってしまします。
どこから原因を探せばよいのか、もしくはどうしたら解決するのかを教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk-core'
```

↓エラーメッセージ

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:34:in `gem_original_require': /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jmespath-1.0.2/lib/jmespath.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
...File.open(path, 'r', encoding: 'UTF-8') { |f| f.read })
                              ^
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jmespath-1.0.2/lib/jmespath.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
...(path, 'r', encoding: 'UTF-8') { |f| f.read })
                              ^
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jmespath-1.0.2/lib/jmespath.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
...oding: 'UTF-8') { |f| f.read })
                              ^
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:34:in `require'
    from s3_test.rb:2
```

バージョンは以下の通りです。

```
# ruby -v
=> ruby 1.8.6 (2010-09-02 patchlevel 420) [i686-linux]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rubyの実行バージョンが古いので新しいハッシュ記法の対応していないようです。

参考： http://qiita.com/yukimura1227/items/8c972efb27667dfac5cd#2-3

まずは Rubyのバージョンを上げて（最低でも1.9以上、できれば最新の2.2.2）、もう一度試してみてください。

Comment: 現在ruby1.8.6で動いてるアプリケーションに組み込みたいのですが、難しいでしょうか、、、

Comment: 単純に考えると選択肢は2つですよね。 1. 現在のアプリを新しいバージョンで動くようにする 2. aws-sdkをフォークして記法を自分で書き換える (1.8系でも動く古いバージョンの aws-sdkを使う(そもそも存在するのか？)、とか、aws-sdkの使用を諦める、というオプションもあるかもですが...) しかし、現実的には1になるでしょう。2だと他にもフォークしないと動かないgemが出てきそうですし、そもそもRuby 1.8 はメンテナンスされていないので使い続けること自体が危険です。 https://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/  1.8系を使い続ける背景は不明ですが、個人的には実行環境のアップデートをオススメします。